# Cómo analizar un endpoint usando JSON para obtener datos de la página de Wunderground

Tags: python, json, scraping

Estoy tratando de obtener uno datos de la pagina Wunderground "`https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/KNYNEWYO1614/table/2023-04-30/2023-04-30/daily`" Pero cuando leo el HTML mis tablas salen vacias con solo los encabezados. So estoy tratando de leer los datos usando un endpoint API ahora mi problema surge cuando trato de anadir fecha al endpoint. Aqui podemos ver que el endpoint funciona para sacar datos del dia actual pero cuando anado las fechas me da un error.

```
endpoint = "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/current?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&stationId=KNYNEWYO1585&numericPrecision=decimal&format=json&units=e" 

response = requests.get(endpoint).json()
print(response)
```

Aqui esta el ejemplo anadiendo fechas.

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

apiKey = "e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525"
station_id = "KNYNEWYO1585"
start_date = "2023-04-30"
end_date = "2023-04-30"

endpoint = f"https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/historical.json?apiKey={apiKey}&stationId={station_id}&format=json&units=e&date={start_date}&endDate={end_date}"

response = requests.get(endpoint).json()["observations"]
weather_data = sorted(response, key=lambda k: k["epoch"])

header = [
    "Time", "Temperature", "Dew Point", "Humidity", "Wind",
    "Wind Speed", "Wind Gust", "Pressure", "Precip.", "Conditions",
]

table = []
for item in weather_data:
    row = [
        datetime.fromtimestamp(item["epoch"]).strftime('%I:%M %p'),
        item["temp"],
        f'{item["dewpt"]} °F',
        f'{item["humidity"]} %',
        item["winddir"],
        item["wspd"],
        f'{item["wgust"] if "wgust" in item else 0} mph',
        f'{item["pressure"]} in',
        f'{item["precip_total"] if "precip_total" in item else "0.0 in"}',
        item["wx_phrase"],
    ]
    table.append(row)

print(tabulate(table, headers=header, tablefmt="pretty"))
```

Este es el error que me da

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-873917b622c8> in <module>
     10 endpoint = f"https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/historical.json?apiKey={apiKey}&stationId={station_id}&format=json&units=e&date={start_date}&endDate={end_date}"
     11 
---> 12 response = requests.get(endpoint).json()["observations"]
     13 weather_data = sorted(response, key=lambda k: k["epoch"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te vengo a proponer una solución utilizando `pandas` y `BeautifulSoup`.

Para empezar, utilicé la url https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/KNYNEWYO1614/table/2023-04-30/2023-04-30/daily

Bueno, la estrategia es bastante sencilla, *parsear* el contenido con `BeautifulSoup` a html. De esta manera podemos acceder a los elementos con el método [.find()](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find#find). Hacemos la búsqueda por el nombre de la *class*. Una vez que obtenemos el elemento deseado, lo trabajamos para encontrar el nombre de las columnas, es decir, el encabezado de la tabla. y las filas correspondientes. Luego de obtener los datos de la tabla, solo resta armar un `DataFrame` con la información extraída.

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


endpoint= "https://www.wunderground.com/dashboard/pws/KNYNEWYO1614/table/2023-04-30/2023-04-30/daily"
response = requests.get(endpoint)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
tabla = soup.find('table', class_='history-table desktop-table')

# Encuentra los nombres de las columnas
encabezados = tabla.find('tr').find_all('th')
nombres_columnas = [encabezado.get_text(strip=True) for encabezado in encabezados]

# Encuentra todas las filas de la tabla
filas = tabla.find_all('tr')

# Crea una lista vacía para almacenar los datos
datos = []

# Itera sobre las filas de la tabla, extrae los datos de cada celda y los agrega a la lista de datos
for fila in filas:
    celdas = fila.find_all('td')
    if celdas:
        fila_datos = [celda.get_text(strip=True) for celda in celdas]
        datos.append(fila_datos)

# Crea el DataFrame utilizando la lista de datos y los nombres de las columnas
df = pd.DataFrame(data=datos, columns=nombres_columnas)
```

el contenido del df:

| Time | Temperature | Dew Point | Humidity | Wind | Speed | Gust | Pressure | Precip. Rate. | Precip. Accum. | UV | Solar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12:04 AM | 50.4°F | 50.0°F | 99°% | ESE | 0.9°mph | 2.9°mph | 29.79°in | 0.00°in | 0.00°in | 0 | 0w/m² |
| 12:09 AM | 50.4°F | 50.0°F | 99°% | North | 0.0°mph | 0.4°mph | 29.79°in | 0.00°in | 0.00°in | 0 | 0w/m² |
| 12:14 AM | 50.4°F | 50.0°F | 99°% | South | 0.2°mph | 1.6°mph | 29.79°in | 0.00°in | 0.00°in | 0 | 0w/m² |

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias